# broken spotify is causing errors

Tags: apt, mount, virtualbox, spotify

So a few days ago I tried to install Spotify and it didn't work... I wasn't that upset since I was installing VirtualBox to run another OS (windows or mac) and had a .iso file on my microSD card. I plug the card into the adapter, plug the adapter into the computer, and it says it can't mount. I've read other forums to fix the mounting but it seems like every single command fails because of this line:

```
E: The list of sources could not be read.
E: Malformed entry 1 in list file /etc/apt/sources.list.d/spotify.list
```

Does anybody have a solution for this?

Comment: What is the contents of the file `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/spotify.list`? It may have an erroneous space or other character in front of the first line.

Comment: `rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/spotify.list` and install spotify as a snap or flatpak.